# A-Frame gltf 2.0 can't set opacity

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, gltf

I import a animated gltf 2.0 model in a A-Frame scene.

I want to set its opacity to 0.5. But it doen't work, even I try to modify the value with object3D class.

Hier is the demo project on glitch:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/animated-gltf-opacity

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the model is loaded, throw Your code to an event listener:

```
this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", (e)=>{//change opacity})
```

Check it out [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-52423883?path=index.html:15:51).

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.